# alignment of UIbutton

Tags: iphone, uibutton

i am working on a simple app containing two tabs with buttons navigating b/w them.as i am new to iphone programming so couldn't align the button to desired position. on searching google i got some code which i have included in my code. i am attaching code

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(method)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"forward" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(60, 70, 70, 60);
[self.view addSubview:button];
button.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
button.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight; //IT IS NOT WORKING
// button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE];
//[button setTitle:fromButton.titleLabel.text forState:UI
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib. 
}
```

as i have aligned the button to right by this code but it is at its default position. No change.
Kindly guide me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentRight;
```

Comment: it is aligning the content shown on button to right..i want the button to be aligned right.

Answer (score 0):

```
button.frame = CGRectMake(120, 70, 70, 60);
```

CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)

Have you played around with [CGRect](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/07/cgrect-tricks/)?

Comment: done that but i want to align my button to left or right or bottom of screen so tell me plz how to do that